# Grid View with gesture and on item click listener

Tags: android, gridview, calendar, gesture, onitemclicklistener

I have a calendar like gridview with both gesture and OnItemClickListener . When the user swipe from left to right the grid view will show next month . When the user swipe the grid view from right to left , it will show the previous month . I use SimpleOnGestureListener for those events . When I click the item of the gridview  , I would like to display the details of the current Item . The problem is When I do only one of those events(Gesture and OnItemClickListener), they work fine . But When I do both , the gesture work fine and  OnItemClickListener doesn't get clicked view , it always get the first view of the row of the clicked item . Help me please . Sorry if my question Bother you , Plus Apologies for my poor English . Thanks .

This is the Code I used to detect Gesture :

```
     public class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 200;
  /*private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;*/

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("single", "singletaps");
        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }


}

public void onSingleTap(View v){

}
public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}
```

And this is the code For onItemClickListener

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);
            String selectedGridDate = CalendarAdapter.dayString
                    .get(position);
            String[] separatedTime = selectedGridDate.split("-");
            String gridvalueString = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*",
                    "");// taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02.
            int gridvalue = Integer.parseInt(gridvalueString);
            // navigate to next or previous month on clicking offdays.
            if ((gridvalue > 10) && (position < 8)) {
                setPreviousMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            } else if ((gridvalue < 7) && (position > 28)) {
                setNextMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            }
            ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);

        }
    });
```

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I have same problem. Return false in **onDown** method helps me:

```
@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How did you solve this issue? Where do you put the above code?

Comment: I put it in the class GestureListener which extends SimpleOnGestureListener

Comment: I tried it the same. Didn't work. I am using the this: http://misha.beshkin.lv/android-swipe-gesture-implementation/ - where do I put it?

Comment: After adding onDown part. Did you add anything else to gridView etc?

Answer (score 0):

i know its old question, but i just encounter same problem recently, so ill try to answer.

I found it hard to use Gesture Class, so instead i use onTouch event, like this :

```
this.mMonthYearContainer.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

then implement the event methods

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.activity_calendar_month_container: {
                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        this.mMonthYearContainer_GestureX1 = event.getX();
                        this.mMonthYearContainer_GestureY1 = event.getY();
                    } break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        this.mMonthYearContainer_GestureX2 = event.getX();
                        this.mMonthYearContainer_GestureY2 = event.getY();
                        float distanceX = this.mMonthYearContainer_GestureX2 - this.mMonthYearContainer_GestureX1;
                        float distanceY = this.mMonthYearContainer_GestureY2 - this.mMonthYearContainer_GestureY1;
                        if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > 50) {
                            if (distanceX > 0) {
                                if (this.mSelectedMonth > 0) {
                                    this.mSelectedMonth -= 1;
                                } else {
                                    this.mSelectedMonth = 12;
                                    this.mSelectedYear -= 1;
                                    this.selectMonthAndYear(this.mSelectedMonth, this.mSelectedYear);
                                }
                                this.selectMonthAndYear(this.mSelectedMonth, this.mSelectedYear);
                            } else {
                                if (this.mSelectedMonth < 12) {
                                    this.mSelectedMonth += 1;
                                } else {
                                    this.mSelectedMonth = 1;
                                    this.mSelectedYear += 1;
                                }
                                this.selectMonthAndYear(this.mSelectedMonth, this.mSelectedYear);
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                        this.mMonthYearContainer_GestureX1 = 0;
                        this.mMonthYearContainer_GestureY1 = 0;
                        this.mMonthYearContainer_GestureX2 = 0;
                        this.mMonthYearContainer_GestureY2 = 0;
                    } break;
                }
            } break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

in this case i put the listener to another view that show the Month and year, but you maybe can implement same method to the calendarview itself